# Add separators and icons to android actionbar popup menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, separator, android-optionsmenu

I'm try to customize my app popup menu adding separators and icons.
Basically I would like to obtain a menu like this (from Google Photos app):

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: check this link [http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html](http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html)

Comment: I use UFT8 emoji as Icons

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a straightforward way to add separators and icons to popup menu.

I suppose, you have to use `PopupWindow`. Using `PopupWindow`, you have to design the layout. So you can design it the way you want, like having icons and separators. But the catch here is, you have to position the `PopupWindow` using `x`,`y` and `gravity` parameters, and also the fade-in animation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: Ok, I thought there was a way to do it like in the NavigationView but i notice that the optionsmenu ignore groups unless you specify android:checkableBehavior. In that case the framework adds a radiobutton to right of the text. But it is not what i'm looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple row in listview to obtain the design,
look at this example: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html